# The Port of the Host URL in Swagger seem to be disappeared after adding extra Path in K8s Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, swagger

I have a spring boot application which has some end points, ex: product/version

I deployed then the application to the K8s network and expose it out using Ingress as below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /productApp
        backend:
          serviceName: productappservice
          servicePort: 80
```

I added a path to the ingress to have my application running under `my-host:8080/productApp/`

In the `Deployment` configuration, I need to add the extra `context-path` to my application using `ConfigMap` to map with the URL that the ingress is exposing:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: product-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: product-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: product-app
          image: my-docer-registry/product-app:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: server.servlet.context-path
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: product-app-values
                  key: server.servlet.context-path

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: product-app-values
data:
   server.servlet.context-path: '/productApp'
```

So now my application is running under `my-host:8080/productApp/` and when I tried to call the API ex: `my-host:8080/productApp/product/version`, it worked fine.

The Problem came when I work with Swagger. I have swagger under: `my-host:8080/productApp/swagger-ui.html` and when I tried to call the `product/version` API, it returned `TypeError: Failed to fetch` . Then I realized that the host URL that swagger is sending request to is no longer `my-host:8080`, it was only `my-host`:

> curl -X GET "http://my-host/productApp/product/version" -H
>   "accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8"

and here is the example json:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
        "title": "Product App REST API"
    },
    "host": "my-host",
    "basePath": "/productApp",
    "tags": [{
        "name": "Product App API",
        "description": "REST API of Product App"
    },
    {
        "name": "version API",
        "description": "Version information of application and REST API"
    }],
    "paths": {
        .....
    }
}
```

What I expect here is the host URL should be `my-host:8080`, instead of only `my-host`, that's why the request in swagger is failed to sent.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Hi @Ock, any luck? Did you figure out how to solve this?

Comment: the idea of ingress is that you don't need to use the port. where are you configuring my-host? I don't see that in the ingress resource definition.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem when using `Istio Ingress`. I solved it by using an Nginx proxy and setting `X-Forwarded-Host` and `X-Forwarded-Port` request headers in Nginx config file to let Swagger know the correct address.